# Звездочки на компьютере отображаются горизонтально в мобильной версии, а на телефоне вертикально

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, почему в мобильной версии на компьютере блок с звёздочками выглядит как надо, а на телефоне он выглядит вертикально, а не горизонтально?

https://kak-nakachat.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое отображение "звёздочек" обусловлено содержанием определённого css.

Comment: А если быть конкретнее?)))

Comment: Откройте css код страницы и смотрите, что там написано.

Comment: В том то и дело, на компьютере все нормально, проблема только на телефоне. Как проверить то?

Comment: я же сказал, откройте css код и смотрите какая его часть вызывает такое поведение ваших звёздочек

Comment: Не смог повторить ошибку - у меня все в порядке со звездочками. Покажите скрин ошибки и приложите размеры экрана, на котором она произошла, пожалуйста

Comment: @artomich ошибка происходит только на телефоне и вот как она выглядит:
http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1597834083/6f5c88fb/31384864.jpg
На компьютере же все отлично

Comment: Попробуйте выставить контейнеру `display: inline-flex;`

Comment: @artomich 

.wpp-list .wpp-rating .webpexpress-processed{
 display: inline-flex;
}

Ввел такой стиль - изменений нет

Answer (score 1):

Ваши звездочки не вмещаются в ширину контейнера так как уменьшается экран, по этому и переносятся.

Comment: А как мне это исправить?

Comment: Ну как минимум вы должны предоставить код

Comment: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1597854348/c62f4dba/31389118.png
Это стили самих звездочек. Проблема заключается в том, что на компьютере все как и должно быть. Проблема только на телефоне, поэтому я не могу ее решить. т.к. не профессионал в этом